# openGL/Glut drawn line not shown from mouse input

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to draw a line based on the mouse input coordinates.

The following code compiles, however, a line is not displayed from mouse input.

```
int coord_1[2]; //(x,y) of first point for line
int coord_2[2]; //(x,y) of second point for line
bool ready_1=false;
bool ready_2=false;

void drawLine()
{
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
     glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glVertex2f(coord_1[0], coord_1[1]);
     glVertex2f(coord_2[0], coord_2[1]);
  glEnd();
}

void display(void) 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if(ready_1 && ready_2)
    {
       drawLine();
       ready_1 = ready_2 = false;
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
   switch (button) 
   {
      case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
         if (state == GLUT_DOWN) //button pressed down
         {
            //only do something on release
         }
         if (state == GLUT_UP) //released button
         {
            cout << "right button up" << endl;
         }
         break;
      case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
         if (state == GLUT_DOWN) //button pressed down
         {
            coord_1[0]=x;
            coord_2[1]=y;
            cout << "first pos" << endl;
            ready_1=true;
          }
          if (state == GLUT_UP) //released button
          {
            coord_2[0]=x;
            coord_2[1]=y;
            cout << "second pos" << endl;
            ready_2=true;
          }
          break;

      default:
          break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);

    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(512,512);
    glutCreateWindow("Asn 1");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);

    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);

    //  GLUT main loop
    glutMainLoop();

   return(0);
}
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction?

Comment: Are the coordinates you're getting in your event handler reasonable? Are they normalized?

Answer (score 0):

You probably draw the line, but since you reset your drawing condition afterwards, your line gets hidden in the next draw step (which might be VERY quick).

Remove the `ready_1 = ready_2 = false;` and the line should stay visible.
Instead you can set `ready_2 = false` when you receive a left button down event.

Comment: This definitely helped, and the line shows now with dummy data entered into drawLine(), thank you.

Comment: @user3291299 If using your actual coordinates are not working, only dummy, refer to the comment on your question. Normalize your coordinates according to your projection matrix